# Convention Java Error Codes

Tags: java, exception

I want to associate error codes to Exceptions.

In this link http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html we can find HTTP Status Codes.

There is any Kind of convention for Java Exception codes, like EJBException?

Comment: Exceptions doesn't have error codes. They have hierarchy.

Comment: You can create your own Exception subclass that has an error code in it, but there is no "convention" for associating exceptions with error codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is no convention for having error codes attached to exception.

You could easily write your own `Exception` to do it like this:

```
public class MyAppException extends Exception
{
    private String errorCode;
    public MyAppException(String errorCode, String message)
    {
        super(message);
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }
    // errorCode getter & setter
}
```